# Using express templates in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, express, meanjs

If I'm using express js to produce my HTML do I still need to use angular to produce the API or do is there another way to go about doing this?

Comment: Furthermore, did you do some reasearch? You can use `angular` to _use and display_ an api in an frontend app - his is nothing which runs on your sever.

Comment: @ventiseis yes I realized this after digging a little deeper. Trying to practice the mean stack just now getting my feet wet. Your feedback is well appreciated though!!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ExpressJS to produce HTML, ExpressJs is for backend development (like API development) while AngularJs is for frontend, when working with MEANJS Application, you need to cmd (Command line), you'll use the first cmd to serve the frontend (gulp serve - if you're using gulp) and use the second to boot your server (node server.js).